# How to send external request to a website which needs authentication - Kohana 3.3

Tags: authentication, request, external, kohana

I am using Kohana 3.3 and trying to make an external request to a url which is internal to our company. The external website needs user credentials. How do i make an external request to that website? I was planning to use a single request to login and then hit the URL i want, but how do i achieve it?. Example code is below.

```
     Request::factory('http://example.com/user/login')->method('POST')->post('username', 'abc')->post('password', '123')->execute();
    $request = Request::$current;

   $request->factory('http://example.com/do/this')->method('POST')->post('param1', 'value')->post('param2', 'value2');
  $response = $request->execute();
```

The above code fails at `$request->factory()` saying its not an object and cannot call factory() method.

Could anyone tell me what is the correct way of doing what i am trying to achieve in Kohana 3.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send external request you should create a request with `Request::factory()` and then `execute()` it. Note that `$request->execute()` returns `Response` object.

To make 2 requests to auth-protected site use:

```
// We create $request object
$request = Request::factory('http://example.com/user/login')
    ->method('POST')
    ->post(array(
        'username' => 'abc',
        'password' => '1111'
    ));

// We execute $request - getting 1st response
$response1 = $request->execute();

// We setting new URL to our $request object and new POST params
$request
    ->url('http://example.com/do/this')
    ->post(array(
        'param1' => '1',
        'param2' => '2'
    ));;

// Now we can execute it again
$response2 = $request->execute();
```

So the idea is - youcan use 1 request object for different actual requests.